# Typescript infer type without using explicit type variable for callback

Tags: typescript, types

I want to wrap rxjs subscribe's `next` callback with my function:

```
type Handler<T> = (value: T) => void;

export function withTryCatch<T>(callback?: Handler<T>): Handler<T> {

  return (value: T) => {
    try {
      callback?.(value);
    } catch(err) {
      // error handling
    }
  };
}
```

Problem with this example bellow is, that it does not automatically infer type from  subscribe's `next` function. In this example, `user` type is stated as `unknown`. Only way how to make user desired type, is to explicitly set `withTryCatch` type variable T (see commented code below - `withTryCatch<UserModel>`).

```
 store$
    .pipe(
      map(userSelector)
    )
    // .subscribe(withTryCatch<UserModel>((user) => {
    .subscribe(withTryCatch((user) => {
      // possible error code
    }));
```

Is there any way how to avoid using `withTryCatch<UserModel>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is separated from place where you use **withTryCatch** function, in that case it's rxjs **subscribe** method. When you just invoke it the generic **T** type parameter is unknown. When you call it with some type parameter then **T** is of course known. You could use Typescript inferring by typing **user** argument like here:

```js
withTryCatch((user: UserModel) => {

});
```

You need to pass callback directly to **subscribe** to use Typescript inferring. Unfortunately it is impossible with that kind of wrapper function